# How to prove product of even permutations is even

Tags: group-theory, permutations

How to prove product of even permutations is even? I've found if the even permutations are disjoint, then it's easy because an even number times another even number is even...so the product of two disjoint even permutations is even...but how about not disjoint even permutations? How to prove then?

Thanks in advance!

(An even permutation of $f$ of $\left \{ 1, 2,\cdots ,n \right \}$ is one with an even number of inversions, that is, pairs $(i,j)$ for which $i<j$ and $f(i)>f(j)$.)

Comment: Consider the steps that you would take to undo a single permutation with adjacent-swaps. Now, consider what would happen if you undid first one, then the other permutation. Hopefully, this should help.

Comment: How you define the even permutation?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: see my edited post, I gave the definition

Comment: So do you know that the signature  of a permutation $\sigma$ is defined by $\epsilon(\sigma)=(-1)^N$ where $N$ is the number of inversions and $\epsilon$ is a group homomorphism?

Comment: @Ian A permutation cannot be both odd and even; if you can find one way to write a permutation as a product of an even number of transpositions, then any other way to write that permutation also has an even number of transpositions. You're asking if composing two even permutations might yield and odd permutation due to not disjoint permutations. Well, if $\sigma,\tau$ both "factor" into even numbers $2m,2n$ of transpositions, then without doing any calculations, ONE way to write $\sigma \tau$ contains $2m+2n$ transpositions, hence any other way to write the product is also even.

Answer (score 7):

One nice trick is to consider the product
$$P(f)=\prod_{i<j} \frac{f(i)-f(j)}{i-j}$$

From your definition of even, it is relatively straightforward to see that
$$P(f)=1$$ when $f$ is even, and $P(f)=-1$ otherwise.

Now to prove your product property, compute $P(fg)$ given $P(f)=P(g)=1$.

Comment: One can go even further, P is a group homomorphism from $S_n$ to $\{-1,1\}$ (under ordinary multiplication) so the multiplicative property holds in general (and not just for the "easy" $P(f) = P(g) = 1$ case).

Answer (score 1):

Write your permutation as a product of transpositions. Then look at the permutation matrix representation of each transposition. Each one has determinant -1. So if you have an even number of transpositions(inversions), then the determinant is 1 and -1 otherwise. So product of any number of even permutations will have permutation matrix determinant 1 implying its even.

Answer (score 1):

Each even permutation can b written as a product of even transposition and then multiply both even permitaion and get product of even permutation necause sum of two even numbers are even...

Comment: You should try to better word the answer. A mathematical statement should stand on its own.

Comment: Please be more precise. For example, you say 'even transposition', when you really mean 'an even number of transpositions'. Also you have several spelling mistakes, please fix these.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_1,...,p_m$ be even permutations. Let $P_1,...,P_m$ be the corresponding permutation matrices. Then $$\det(\prod_{i=1}^m P_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{m}\det(P_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{m}(1) = 1$$

Therefore, the product of permutations $\prod_{i=1}^{m} p_i$, which the product of permutation matrices $\prod_{i=1}^m P_i$ corresponds is even.